# Custom width for submenus in CSS

Tags: css, width

I can only set an even width for the `"<li>"` inside the `"<ul>"`. How do I distribute them proportionally according to their contents?
I can only set the width with a fixed size expressed in px or as a precentage.

thanks

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle of your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xdfu82ao/

Comment: Try `ul { overflow: hidden; } li { width: auto; float: left; }`

Comment: if I set the width to auto it leaves no space between the text at all.

Comment: found it, sounds simple now but it didn't cross my mind. I set the width to auto and write "margin-left:20px" and "margin-right:20px". thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table / table-cell`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5f1omyfh/1/)

CSS

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;    
}
```